#  Madwifi Driver Installation Error : "Cannot detect kernel version"

Tags: drivers, compiling, madwifi

I cannot get past this error when trying to run "make" on the driver source.

```
Makefile.inc:81: *** Cannot detect kernel version - please check compiler and KERNELPATH. Stop.
```

Does anyone know the procedure for installing madwifi drivers on Ubuntu **11.10**?

Notes:

I have all the necessary packages installed including the linux headers and have also tried specifying the "KERNELPATH" manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used svn for the newest release and received no issues when compiling or installing.

Comment: Google search turned up questions about the same error with no resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Just install module-assistant and choose the madwifi from the module assistant list, this will allow you to download, compile and install the modules.

Comment: madwifi drivers are not in the repository so it doesn't work and yes I enabled the 3rd party sources.

Comment: Ok [here](http://www.punknix.com/?q=node/110) is a link to a tutorial for debian, i guess you should make it work or add debian repository to your sources.lst.

Comment: tried adding those repositories and 10.04 repositories and it doesn't work... would prefer not to install a driver compiled for an older version anyways.

Comment: you can try downloading the latest source from the madwifi site and than try to install it with module assistant.

Comment: not sure how I would instruct module-assistant to use the downloaded source... it says it makes and installs "debianized" source in the man file.