# How to install madwifi?

Tags: 11.10, wireless, madwifi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>    [Madwifi Driver Installation Error : “Cannot detect kernel version”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66997/madwifi-driver-installation-error-cannot-detect-kernel-version)

I want to use the wlanconfig tool on my newly installed Ubuntu 11.10. However I cannot find the madwifi package to install with. I tried to install the module-assistant and used module-assistant to auto install madwifi package. Apparently the madwifi package is not available.

How can I install the wlanconfig tool then? I thought it is installed as default, but I am wrong.